# How to solve Unparseable date:error in spring-boot

Tags: spring, date, spring-boot, datepicker

I having difficulty trying to solve an error with my date in Spring. I think i have exhausted almost all the solution on stack overflow an i still do not have a solution. I have implement a customDateEditor and i am still get the same error.
I am using the datepicker to select the date on the form.

Error

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property date; nested exception is


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "1 March, 2017"
```

Model

```
@NotNull(message = "Date field must not be blank.")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date date;
 public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date)  {
        this.date = date;
    }
```

Controller

```
 @InitBinder
    public void allowEmptyDateBinding( WebDataBinder binder )
    {
        // Custom String Editor. tell spring to set empty values as null instead of empty string.
        binder.registerCustomEditor( String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor( true ));

        //Custom Date Editor

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor( Date.class, new CustomDateEditor( simpleDateFormat,true));
    }
```

Form

```
<input th:type="date" class="form-control input-sm datepicker" th:field="*{date}"
                       placeholder="Date Of Birth"/>
```

JS Script

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    autoclose: true,
    Format: 'dd-MM-yyyy'
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually using [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) rather than [jquery-ui datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

And [according to documentation](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#formats_use_hidden_only), you are supposed to give 'formatSubmit' property to ensure format of submitted date.

Another issue is your date format for javascript and Java code does not match. 
Format `'dd-MM-yyyy'` for *SimpleDateFormat* class will give `01-03-2017`, 
while for *pickatedate.js* you need to give `'dd-mm-yyyy'` as format.

Therefore, for your "JS script" you should use

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
    formatSubmit: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
  });
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I went through the documentation i did not see that till you pointed it out.

Comment: same exception for me but I didn't use any js pugin or library
just using `<input type="date" id="submitDate" th:field="*{submitDate}" required />`